# Forçar classe no react a usar arrow function com eslint

Tags: javascript, react, eslint, arrow-functions

Como faço pro ESLint dar erro quando alguém no projeto usar functions dentro de uma class que necessitam de bind no lugar de uma arrow function

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar esse plugin do eslint pra fazer isso: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow

Exemplo:

```
"plugins": [
  "prefer-arrow"
],
"rules": [
  "prefer-arrow/prefer-arrow-functions": [
     "error",
     {
       "disallowPrototype": true,
       "singleReturnOnly": false,
       "classPropertiesAllowed": false
     }
   ]
]
```